# jQuery: Only show content that is visible from current view and load the rest on scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a very long set of `<li>` elements inside an `<ul>` menu that require the user to scroll down for a long time to reach the bottom of the page. How can I use jQuery to only load the content which is visible on his screen from the current view (depending on his resolution) and load the rest of the list only when the user is scrolling down?

Again, let's assume this very simple layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
           <ul class="posts">
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              ...
           </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you going to pay for this code? Show us your trials first!

Comment: @Ashraf: My intention was not to get the working code but a direction at what toolkit to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below link might help you.

[jquery-endless-scroll](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll)

and

[jQuery Plugins](http://megahitmag.com/free-infinite-scrolling-jquery-plugins/)

Comment: I will mark this as best. Thanks! It contains very useful information to go further. In fact jquery-endless-scroll is already very much what I wanted.

Comment: Hey, I am really glad it helped you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [stroll.js](http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/) if you also want to add some effects (it doesn't require jQuery):

```
<ul id="posts-list">
  ...
</ul>

stroll.bind(document.getElementById('posts-list'));
```

And the base CSS:

```
html,
body,
.container {
  height: 100%;
}

#posts-list {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you change your design. As if you only show what is visible the scroll bars won't be there and scrolling not possible. You want to implement infinite scroll instead, where you click 'show more' or something.
If you want to show more on scroll, you must show more than is visible.